# Create custom follow button for my application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like a directive that dynamically knows if I'm following the user in my App.

I have a resource to get the currentUser

```
    this.following = function () {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        var user = $cookies.getObject('currentUser');
        UserResource.get({id: user.id}).$promise.then(
            function (data) {
                defer.resolve(data.following);
            });
        return defer.promise;
    };
```

This is in one of my services. It returns all users that I'm following.

When instantiating my controller I fetch the users I follow within my app:

```
   UserService.following().then(
        function (data) {
            $scope.following = data;
        });
```

I would like to move that into a directive so that I can easily reuse it somewhere else in my app.

This is the HTML I am using right now (and it's not really beautiful) :

```
   <div class="item" ng-repeat="user in users">
        <div class="right floated content">
            <div ng-show="isFollowing(user)" class="ui animated flip button" tabindex="0"
                 ng-click='unFollow(user)'>
                <div class='visible content'>
                    Following
                </div>
                <div class="hidden content">
                    Unfollow
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-hide="isFollowing(user)" ng-click="follow(user)" class="ui button">Follow</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But instead something like :

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="user in users">
      <um-follow-button um-user="user"></um-follow-button>
</div>
```

then depending if I'm following the user or not then render one of the two options.

I don't know if I will have to use a controller in my directive.

I have looked at : https://gist.github.com/jhdavids8/6265398
But it looks like a mess.

Comment: What is not happening that should?

Comment: @Adjit Well I'm fetching twice the isFollowing because of the rendering. That's one of the reason I need to change this to a directive. And since  I have dom logic it's better to use a directive. I do not have a directive right now.